# Transactionscope.Required not workings for first item in list

Tags: c#, transactionscope

I am using SQLServer with C#.

```
foreach(var item in list)
{
  TransactionOptions transOption = new TransactionOptions();
  transOption.IsolationLevel = 
    System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted;

  using (TransactionScope scope = new 
  TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, transOption))
  {
     //Code to select
     //Code to insert

   scope.Complete();
  }
}
```

For first time(1st item from list) transaction not getting committed. but I can see select and insert queries in SQL Profiler. There is no exception in any where.

But second time (2nd item from list) and also remaining items getting committed.

If I change into `TransactionScopeOption.Suppress`, first item itself getting committed. But I dont know what is 'Suppress'

```
TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Suppress, transOption))
  {
     //Code to select
     //Code to insert

   scope.Complete();
  }
```

So any idea why `TransactionScopeOption.Required` and `TransactionScopeOption.RequiredNew` not working to commit? What changes I need to do to get commit?

Advance thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say why there is the strange behaviour with the 1st item. But you should know a couple of things here:

#### Transactions committing

The actual commit happens  not on `scope.Complete();`, it happens when `TransactionScope` is being disposed.

#### TransactionScopeOptions

**`TransactionScopeOption.Required`** guarantees that insructions in the scope will be wrapped by transaction. It can be achieved by two ways: a) if there is an ambient outer transaction then inner scope doesn't create the own transaction. The actual commit happens if `outerScope.Complete()` was invoked and then the outer transaction scope is disposed b) if there is no outer transactions then it creates its own transaction.

**`TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew`** always creates its own independent transaction.

**`TransactionScopeOption.Suppress`**  doesn't create any transaction and ignores any outer transaction. Since there is no any transaction to save changes it doesn't require `scope.Complete();` and you can't rollback changes.

I hope this information will help you to understand what happens in your particular case.

Comment: outerScope.Complete() - i think we have outer NHibernate session.
TransactionScopeOption.Required-- will it commit once entire list completed? means end of foreach.

Comment: Basically, outer `TransactionScope` is not the outer `NHibernate` session. `TransactionScopeOption.Required` should create a new transaction on each iteration. Since your code example is not complete I can't answer to your question. I think you are able to answer to you question by yourself. Just try it in debug.

Answer (score 0):

Try restructuring your code, like this:

```
 TransactionOptions transOption = new TransactionOptions();
 transOption.IsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted;

 using (TransactionScope scope = new 
 TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, transOption))
 {
      foreach(var item in enter code here`list)
      {
           //your code
           scope.Complete();
      }
 }
```

Refer to [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/25f037ca-886c-4563-b169-d724b6047a99/transactionscopeoptionsuppress-questions?forum=windowstransactionsprogramming) forum question for more details on what Supress is.

Comment: Yes I can do what you said but I would like to commit each item instead of waiting to complete entire list. Because the list containing more than 50 records.

Comment: @KathirVey please see my edit. I put the scope.Complete() inside the loop to commit every insert one by one.

Comment: tried but this also gives an error. error like transaction expected rows:2 but actual:1 for second item.